# Place holder is not working in editor text area in TINYMCE

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-6

We tried Adding placeholder in `tinymce.init`, it is not showing in textarea.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",
 ** placeholder: "Enter paragraph text. Highlight the text to apply styling.",**
  skin: false,
  icons: '',
  menubar: false,
});
```

We are able to see it in HTML content, but not displaying in text area [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWMiQ.png)

Actual Result: Not displaying placeholder in textarea.

[image]

Expected Result: To display placeholder in textarea.
[image]